# Enable automatic server reloading in Vite for real-time updates

Tags: node.js, server, proxy, vite

Everyime I make a change on the server I need to restart my vite proxy server for the changes to apply. The native node.js watch fixes it, but I still need to refresh the browser. How can I enable Hot-Reloading in this case? Any solution?

Here's my server config in vite.config.js:

```
server: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8000',
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false,
            ws: true,
            timeout: 10000,
            rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: What about using nodemon?

Comment: @Steve I use Node.js 18.11+ native watch param that replaces nodemon and does the same job, but it doesn't solve this issue. I'm talking about vite proxy server.